# 'FinalProject.projectDBEntities1' does not contain a definition for 'Table'

Tags: c#, sql

This is my first time connecting to a database with c# and I'm getting an error that says:

> Error 1   'FinalProject.projectDBEntities1' does not contain a definition for 'Table' and no extension method 'Table' accepting a first argument of type 'FinalProject.projectDBEntities1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I thought I was doing this right, but apparently not. Here is a screenshot showing what I would think is everything you need to see to identify the issue. Why am I getting this error?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejQp1.png

Comment: If you look on the left at the server explorer, you will see the database with the table named table I believe. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Tables.Table rather than DBProjectblahblah.Table.

The only other thing I can think of is if you hover over the blue underlines word "Table" Visual Studio will sometimes tell you if you are missing a reference. If so hooray.

I hope this helps you somehow.